# edge detection on depth buffer [cel shading]

Tags: edge-detection, depth-buffer

I am currently writing a cel shading shader, but I'm having issues with edge detection. I am currently using the following code utilizing laplacian edge detection on non-linear depth buffer values:

```
uniform sampler2d depth_tex;
void main(){
vec4 color_out;
float znear = 1.0;
float zfar = 50000.0;
float depthm = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).r;
float lineAmp = mix( 0.001, 0.0, clamp( (500.0 / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depthm - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) )/2.0), 0.0, 1.0 ) );// make the lines thicker at close range

float depthn = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2( (0.002 + lineAmp)*0.625 , 0.0) ).r;
depthn = depthn / depthm;

float depths = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - vec2( (0.002 + lineAmp)*0.625 , 0.0) ).r;
depths = depths / depthm;

float depthw = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2(0.0 , 0.002 + lineAmp) ).r;
depthw = depthw / depthm;

float depthe = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - vec2(0.0 , 0.002 + lineAmp) ).r;
depthe = depthe / depthm;

float Contour = -4.0 + depthn + depths + depthw + depthe;

float lineAmp2 = 100.0 * clamp( depthm - 0.99, 0.0, 1.0);
lineAmp2 = lineAmp2 * lineAmp2;
Contour = (512.0 + lineAmp2 * 204800.0 ) * Contour;

if(Contour > 0.15){
    Contour = (0.15 - Contour) / 1.5 + 0.5;
} else
    Contour = 1.0;

color_out.rgb = color_out.rgb * Contour;
    color_out.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = color_out;
}
```

but it is hackish[note the lineAmp2], and the details at large distances are lost. So I made up some other algorithm:

[Note that Laplacian edge detection is in use]

1.Get 5 samples from the depth buffer: depthm, depthn, depths, depthw, depthe, where depthm is exactly where the processed fragment is, depthn is slightly to the top, depths is slightly to the bottom etc.

2.Calculate their real coordinates in camera space[as well as convert to linear].

3.Compare the side samples to the middle sample by substracting and then normalize each difference by dividing by difference in distance between two camera-space points and add all four results. This should in theory help with situation, where at large distances from the camera two fragments are very close on the screen but very far in camera space, which is fatal for linear depth testing.

where:

2.a convert the non linear depth to linear using an algorithm from [url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer[/url]
exact code:

```
uniform sampler2D depthBuffTex;
uniform float zNear;
uniform float zFar;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main(void)
{
float z_b = texture2D(depthBuffTex, vTexCoord).x;
float z_n = 2.0 * z_b - 1.0;
float z_e = 2.0 * zNear * zFar / (zFar + zNear - z_n * (zFar - zNear));
}
```

2.b convert the screen coordinates to be [tan a, tan b], where a is horizontal angle and b i vertical. There probably is a better terminology with some spherical coordinates but I don't know these yet.

2.c create a 3d vector ( converted screen coordinates, 1.0 ) and scale it by linear depth. I assume this is estimated camera space coordinates of the fragment. It looks like it.

3.a each difference is as follows: (depthm - sidedepth)/lenght( positionm - sideposition)

And I may have messed up something at any point. Code looks fine, but the algorithm may not be, as I made it up myself.

My code:

```
uniform sampler2d depth_tex;
void main(){
float znear = 1.0;
float zfar = 10000000000.0;

float depthm = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort ).r;
depthm = 2.0 * zfar * znear / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depthm - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) );    //convert to linear
vec2 scorm = (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort) -0.5;    //conversion to desired coordinates space. This line returns value from range (-0.5,0.5)
scorm = scorm * 2.0 * 0.5;     // normalize to (-1, 1) and multiply by tan FOV/2, and default fov is IIRC 60 degrees
scorm.x = scorm.x * 1.6;      //1.6 is aspect ratio 16/10
vec3 posm = vec3( scorm, 1.0 );
posm = posm * depthm;      //scale by linearized depth



float depthn = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort + vec2( 0.002*0.625  , 0.0) ).r;          //0.625 is aspect ratio 10/16
depthn = 2.0 * zfar * znear / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depthn - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) );
vec2 scorn = (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort + vec2( 0.002*0.625, 0.0) ) -0.5;
scorn = scorn * 2.0 * 0.5;
scorn.x = scorn.x * 1.6;
vec3 posn = vec3( scorn, 1.0 );
posn = posn * depthn;

float depths = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort - vec2( 0.002*0.625 , 0.0) ).r;
depths = 2.0 * zfar * znear / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depths - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) );
vec2 scors = (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort - vec2( 0.002*0.625, 0.0) ) -0.5;
scors = scors * 2.0 * 0.5;
scors.x = scors.x * 1.6;
vec3 poss = vec3( scors, 1.0 );
poss = poss * depths;

float depthw = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort + vec2(0.0 , 0.002) ).r;
depthw = 2.0 * zfar * znear / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depthw - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) );
vec2 scorw = ( gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort + vec2( 0.0 , 0.002) ) -0.5;
scorw = scorw * 2.0 * 0.5;
scorw.x = scorw.x * 1.6;
vec3 posw = vec3( scorw, 1.0 );
posw = posw * depthw;

float depthe = texture2D(depth_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort - vec2(0.0 , 0.002) ).r;
depthe = 2.0 * zfar * znear / (zfar + znear - ( 2.0 * depthe - 1.0 ) * (zfar - znear) );
vec2 score = ( gl_TexCoord[0].xy + distort - vec2( 0.0 , 0.002) ) -0.5;
score = score * 2.0 * 0.5;
score.x = score.x * 1.6;
vec3 pose = vec3( score, 1.0 );
pose = pose * depthe;

float Contour = ( depthn - depthm )/length(posm - posn) + ( depths - depthm )/length(posm - poss) + ( depthw - depthm )/length(posm - posw) + ( depthe - depthm )/length(posm - pose);
Contour = 0.25 * Contour;

color_out.rgb = vec3( Contour, Contour, Contour );
    color_out.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = color_out;
}
```

The exact issue with the second code is that it exhibits some awful artifacts at larger distances.

My goal is to make either of them work properly. Are there any tricks I could use to improve precision/quality in both linearized and non-linearized depth buffer? Is anything wrong with my algorithm for linearized depth buffer?