# opengl using depth buffer for shadows- any reason not to just render z to tex rather than use depth buffer?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, shadow-mapping

So I'm working on implementing shadow mapping. So far, I've rendered the geometry (depth, normals, colors) to a framebuffer from the camera's point of view, and rendered the depth of the geometry from the light's point of view. Now, I'm rendering the lighting from the camera's point of view, and for each fragment, I'm to compare its distance to the light, to the depth tex value from the render-from-the-lights-pov pass. If the distance is greater, it's in shadow. (Just recapping here to make sure there isn't anything I don't realize I don't understand).

So, to do this last step, I need to convert the depth value [0-1] to its eye-space value [0.1-100] (my near/far planes). (explanation here- [Getting the true z value from the depth buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer)).

Is there any reason to not instead just have the render-from-the-lights-pov pass just write to a texture the distance of the fragment to the camera (the z component) directly? Then we won't have to deal with the ridiculous conversion? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly write your own depth value to a texture, and many people do just that. The advantage of doing that is that you can choose whatever representation and mapping you like.

The downside is that you have to either a) still have a "real" depth buffer attached to your FBO (and therefore double up the bandwidth you're using for depth writing), or b) use GL_MIN/GL_MAX blending mode (depending on how you are mapping depth) and possibly miss out on early-z out optimizations.