# Render depth to texture

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, framebuffer

I can't get my depth to render correctly. No errors are thrown, the glCheckFramebufferStatus says it is complete as well.

Below is the code, the screen always shows up white. The depth values are not 1, but very very close:

## EDIT:

So I tried linearizing the depth inside of my depth fragment shader and then drawing that directly to the screen to make sure the values were correct. They are correct. However, even if I send that linearized depth to my full screen quad shader (the 2nd one below), the screen is still all white.

```
public void initFramebuffers() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthShader.fbo);
    depthShader.initTexture(width, height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthShader.tex, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
}

public void initTexture(int width, int height, int format, int internalFormat) {
    tex = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer)null);
}
```

Depth Shader:

```
#version 400

in vec3 pos;
in float radius;

uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

out float depth;

float linearizeDepth(float depth) {
    float n = 0.01;
    float f = 100;
    return (2.0 * n) / (f + n - depth * (f - n));
}    

void main() {
    //calculate normal
    vec3 normal;
    normal.xy = gl_PointCoord * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float r2 = dot(normal.xy, normal.xy);
    
    if (r2 > 1.0) {
        discard;
    }
    
    normal.z = sqrt(1.0 - r2);

    //calculate depth
    vec4 pixelPos = vec4(pos + normal * radius, 1.0);
    vec4 clipSpacePos = projection * pixelPos;
    
    depth = clipSpacePos.z / clipSpacePos.w * 0.5f + 0.5f;
    depth = linearizeDepth(depth);
}
```

Shader that reads in the depth. The values in linearizeDepth are my near and far distances:

```
#version 400

in vec2 coord;

uniform sampler2D depthMap;
uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec4 color;

float linearizeDepth(float depth) {
    float n = 0.01;
    float f = 100;
    return (2.0 * n) / (f + n - depth * (f - n));
}    

void main() {
    float curDepth = texture2D(depthMap, coord).x;
    //float d = linearizeDepth(curDepth);

    color = vec4(d, d, d, 1.0f);
}
```

Code for drawing everything:

```
//--------------------Particle Depth-----------------------
{
    glUseProgram(depthShader.program);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthShader.fbo);

    depthShader.particleDepthVAO(points);
    
    //Sets uniforms
    RenderUtility.addMatrix(depthShader, mView, "mView");
    RenderUtility.addMatrix(depthShader, projection, "projection");
    RenderUtility.addVector2(depthShader, screenSize, "screenSize");
    RenderUtility.addVector3(depthShader, lightPosition, "lightPos");
            
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(depthShader.vao);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, points.size());  
}

    //Draw full screen
{
    glUseProgram(blurShader.program);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
                
    blurShader.blurDepthVAO();
                
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthShader.tex);
    glUniform1i(blurShader.depthMap, 0);
    
    //Sets uniforms 
    RenderUtility.addMatrix(blurShader, mView, "mView");
    RenderUtility.addMatrix(blurShader, projection, "projection");
    RenderUtility.addVector2(blurShader, screenSize, "screenSize");
                
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                
    glBindVertexArray(blurShader.vao);
                
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit questions in ways that invalidate answers.

Comment: That was not the purpose. The purpose was to reflect the current state of my code which it had been in before I saw your answer. Leaving it in that condition was simply a mistake on my part, I neglected to update it.

Comment: It may be a bit late, but imho there is still a mistake while linearizing the depth value. You may not all it a mistake, if it works for you, but there is another way to linearize the depth (which works for me). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer/6657284#6657284
In this formula another f is multiplied to the return value of the linDepth() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that my vertex shader's out variable name didn't match the fragment shader's in variable name (doh). The code posted above is 100% correct in case anyone sees this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the posted code.

### Inconsistent use of render target

In the setup of the FBO, there is only a depth attachment, and no color attachment. The color draw buffer is also explicitly disabled:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthShader.tex, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

However, the fragment shader writes a color output:

```
out float depth;
...
    depth = clipSpacePos.z / clipSpacePos.w * 0.5f + 0.5f;
    depth = linearizeDepth(depth);
```

To write to the depth attachment of the framebuffer, you will have to set the value of the predefined `gl_FragDepth` variable. Just because the out variable is named `depth` does not mean that it's actually used as the depth output. If you want to use the color output, you'll have to create a regular texture, and attach it to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Which would actually seem easier.

### linearizeDepth() calculation

```
float linearizeDepth(float depth) {
    float n = 0.01;
    float f = 100;
    return (2.0 * n) / (f + n - depth * (f - n));
}

depth = clipSpacePos.z / clipSpacePos.w * 0.5f + 0.5f;
depth = linearizeDepth(depth);
```

The way the `clipSpacePos` is processed, it looks like the arguments to `linarizeDepth()` will be between 0.0 and 1.0. The calculation inside the function for these extreme values is then:

```
0.0 --> (2.0 * n) / (f + n)
1.0 --> 1.0
```

This looks fine for 1.0, but questionable for 0.0. I believe it would actually be more correct to make the preparation step:

```
depth = clipSpacePos.z / clipSpacePos.w;
```

This will then pass arguments between -1.0 and 1.0 to the function, which then produces:

```
-1.0 --> n / f
1.0  --> 1.0
```

It would actually make even more sense to me to scale the whole thing to produce results between 0.0 and 1.0, but at least this version makes intuitive sense, producing the relative distance to the far plane.

### Calculation more complex than necessary

The above looks unnecessarily convoluted to me. You're applying the projection matrix, take the depth from the result, and then effectively invert the depth calculation applied by the projection matrix.

It would seem a whole lot simpler to not apply the projection matrix in the first place, and simply take the original distance. You can still divide by the far distance if you want a relative distance. At least as long as you use a standard projection matrix, I believe the following is equivalent to the corrected calculation above:

```
vec4 pixelPos = vec4(pos + normal * radius, 1.0);
float f = 100.0;  // far plane
depth = -pixelPos.z / f;
```

The minus sign comes in because the most commonly used eye coordinate system assumes that you're looking down the negative z-axis.

If you wanted results between 0.0 and 1.0, you could also change this to:

```
float n = 0.01;   // near plane
float f = 100.0;  // far plane
depth = (-pixelPos.z - n) / (f - n);
```

Comment: Linearizing within the depth fragment shader was incorrect and has been corrected. That linearizing function though seems to be the standard according to what I've read online. In addition, the shaders are implemented based on http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2010/gdc/Direct3D_Effects.pdf