# Metal + ARKit — Get z distance to current fragment in fragment shader

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, metal

I have a metal shader (written as a `SCNProgram` for an ARKit app) that takes a depth map of the current scene captured from [`smoothedSceneDepth`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/3674209-smoothedscenedepth). I would like to use the captured depth information to discard parts of any of my virtual objects that are behind a real world object. However I am having trouble getting the expected fragment depth in my shader.

Here's my basic fragment shader:

```cpp
struct ColorInOut {
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float2 depthTexCoords;
};

fragment float4 fragmentShader(
    const ColorInOut in [[ stage_in ]],
    depth2d<float, access::sample> sceneDepthTexture [[ texture(1) ]]
) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler(mag_filter::linear, min_filter::linear);
    
    // Closest = 0.0m, farthest = 5.0m (lidar max)
    // Seems to be in meters?
    const float lidarDepth = sceneDepthTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.depthTexCoords);
 
    float fragDepth = // ??? somehow get z distance to the current fragment in meters ???

    // Compare the distances
    const float zMargin = 0.1
    if (lidarDepth < fragDepth - zMargin) {
         discard_fragement()
    }

    ...
}
```

My understanding was that `position.z` in a fragment shader should be in the range of closest=0 to farthest=1. However when I tried converting this back to real world distances using the current camera planes, the result seem off:

```cpp
const float zNear = 0.001;
const float zFar = 1000;

float fragDepth = in.position.z * (zFar - zNear);
```

When I debugged the shader using `return float4(fragDepth, 0, 0, 1);`, the red is brightest when I am closest to the object and then falls off as I back away. Even if I use `fragDepth = 1 - fragDepth`, the depth seems to differ from `lidarDepth`.

Here's using `1 - fragDepth`:

[image: Using 1 - fragDepth]

(I also tried using the mapping from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer) but wasn't able to get it working)

So my questions are:

- What coordinate system is `in.position.z` in?
- How can I transform `in.position.z` into a depth value I can compare against the captured depth information I already have? (or vice versa)

Comment: « Even if I use `fragDepth = 1 - fragDepth`, the depth seems to differ from `lidarDepth` » how different are they? Do you have a screenshot? Have you tried using `SCNSceneBuffer`'s `inverseProjectionTransform`?

Comment: There's a fairly hard edge where the depth goes from all black to middle red. I've added a screenshot of this. If `fragDepth` is in meters, this should be much more gradual. The core problem is that I don't know what coordinate space `in.position.z` is in though because I would not expect that  `1 - fragDepth` would be required at all

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I haven't entirely convinced myself the following solution is correct but it seems to work for my very basic application:

In the vertex shader, I write out the position in eye space:

```cpp
// in vertex shader
out.fragEyePosition = scn_node.modelViewTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
```

In the fragment shader, I can then use `-in.fragEyePosition.z` for the depth test:

```cpp
// in fragment shader

float depth = -in.fragEyePosition.z;

const float zMargin = 0.1;
if (lidarDepth - depth < -zMargin) {
    discard_fragment();
}

...
```

I'd appreciate an explanation of why this works and why my previous attempt using `.position` did not (or a correction if the solution I here has some issues)